# asp.net web api 2.1 getting null object in controller with content type application xml

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-web-api2

I have Api controller which has only POST and PUT

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]object msg)
    {
        _logger.Log.Info("Got message: " + msg.ToString());
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Put(object msg)
    {
        _logger.Log.Info("Got message: " + msg.ToString());
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

3rd party component is sending me requests with content type of application/xml

```
<EventList>
<Event>
    <EventSubTypeId>65</EventSubTypeId>
    <ExternalEventId>1</ExternalEventId>
    <Direction>West</Direction>
    <Road>I 70</Road>
    <StartMileMarker>71.0</StartMileMarker>
    <EndMileMarker>72.0</EndMileMarker>
    <IsBothDirectionFlag>false</IsBothDirectionFlag>
    <StartDate>2014-09-08T15:01:01.190-06:00</StartDate>
    <Latitude>39.941208</Latitude>
    <Longitude>-105.140121</Longitude>
    <FatalityFlag>false</FatalityFlag>
    <HazmatFlag>false</HazmatFlag>
    <EstimatedTimeToClear>Test Estimated time to clear</EstimatedTimeToClear>
    <GroupName>ITS</GroupName>
    <Severity>Minimal</Severity>
    <Classification>None</Classification>
    <RoadwayClosure>No Lanes Closed</RoadwayClosure>
</Event>
```

however no matter how I try I am always getting null in the msg object
I have also tried

```
var xml = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter;
        xml.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

what is the solution?

Comment: try taking it to string type, how can you expect this to be sync ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]string msg)
    {
XDocument xmlMessage =                 XDocument.Parse(msg);
        _logger.Log.Info("Got message: " + msg.ToString());
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options:

1. Create a class for the parameter `object` instead of an anonymous type(`object`).
2. Or if you want to receive the anonymous instance, you should remove XML formatter, because anonymous types [are not supported by XML Formatter](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization):

> The XML serializer does not support *anonymous types* or **JObject** instances. I

Therefore in your code `object msg` is not valid with XML Serializer.

Comment: I have create event List class - basically i have it as i am sending them also data, but still get null. do i need to decorate it with attributes?

Comment: @li-raz is your class serializable, try adding [DataContract] or [Serialazable] to ensure it is